# How to use recursion to divide a number multiple times and keep track of the iterations?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to make a function that will half the integer argument until it's under 1. I also want to keep track of how many iterations it took for it to do this. Here is what I have so far, but I am stuck on what to put in the recursive case:

```
def case(number):
    if number == 1:
       return 1
    else:
       return number * 0.50    # not sure how to do this part
case(20)
```

So for example, if I had 20 passed as an argument for "case", I want the recursive case/ function to do 20 * 0.50 (or 20/2)= 10, then take 10 * 0.50 = 5,
then take 5 * 0.50 ect.. until the number is under 1.

In this example, it would have taken 6 iterations to get below 1 (0.625).

How do you get the recursive case to keep dividing or taking half of the number and for it to print the amount of iterations it took to the console?

**Note:** I'm aware that while loops would be a lot more suited for this situation, but the project I'm working, recursion will make it easier later.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def case(number):
    if number <= 1: # base case (exit)
       return 1
    else:
       return 1+case(number * 0.50) # recursive case
```

Comment: why `1+`? I think the exit condition is correct, but recursive case just needs to return the self call of the function with the altered argument.

Comment: because it returns the number of ops it takes ... without 1+ it would always just return 1 ...

Answer (score 1):

```py
def case(number, t=0):
    if number < 1:
        return (number,t)
    else:
        return case(number/2, t+1)
```

This will return a tuple containing the number (e.g. `0.625`) and the number of iterations (e.g. `6`)

The parameter `t` represents the number of iterations.

When `number` is less than one, nothing else needs to be done, so we return the tuple `(number, t)`. If `number` is greater than or equal to 1, will return the result of calling `case` with `number/2` as the first parameter (`number`) and `t+1` as the second parameter (`t`). This way `t` is incremented once for every level of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def case(number):
   return recursiveFunc(number, 0, 0.5)
def recursiveFunc(number, count, multiplier):
    if(number <= 1):
       return count
    return recursiveFunc(number*multiplier, count+1, multiplier)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def case(number,count):
    if number < 1:
       return "Taken %s iteration to get below 1 (%s)" % (count,number)
    return case(number * 0.5, count+1)  

print case(20, 0)
```